# Why does my WordPress site title have a "-" in front of it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update my site title to say "Welcome to Etheric City". I did this just simply in the wordpress site identity tab and it worked but I have a random dash ("-") in front of it now like the image here -->
[image]

The code in the header.php file doesn't show any dashes so was wondering what I'm missing? I entered in the site title manually and didn't copy and paste from anywhere. Header.php code below:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Signify
 */

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'wp_body_open' ); ?>

<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'signify-music-dark' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <div class="site-header-main">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/site', 'branding' ); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'primary' ); ?>
            </div><!-- .wrapper -->
        </div><!-- .site-header-main -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <?php signify_sections(); ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Its display inside head or document section. You can remove using filter hook.
Reference : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/

```
 /**
 * Remove title whitespace.
 */

  function modify_document_title_separator( $separator ) {
    return "";
  }
  add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'modify_document_title_separator', 10, 1 );
```